# Good book on Galois connections?

Tags: reference-request

What are some good introductory books on Galois connections? I have read *Galois Theory* from Emil Artin, *Algebra* from Saunder Mac Lane, and I'm starting Serge Lang.

Comment: Do you mean [Galois Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) or *abstract* [Galois connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection) ?

Comment: I simultaneously feel that this is not a very good question and have a lot of sympathy for it.  I have had occasion to wonder in recent years "Why isn't there a book on Galois Connections that takes the perspective I want?" Part of the problem being that I'm not really sure what perspective I want...but I'd probably know it if I saw it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steven Roman's book [Field Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387276777) treats the Galois Theory part of his book using Galois connections. I don't have the book but I had browsed through it one time when I was looking for a different book in my university library, and I have to say that it seemed pretty good.

In particular, take a look at chapter 6, where he develops some theory about Galois connections and applies it to study the Galois correspondence.

Answer (score 4):

George Bergman's [Universal Algebra book](http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/)  has a chapter that discusses Galois connections ([Chapter 5](http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/Ch.5.pdf)); the link is to the PDF version. I like it, though it's not very extensive (just six pages).